# Unexpected service behavior

Tags: android, service

I am trying to create a `Service` that opens a stackoverflow site every 24 hours and my code looks like this:

```
public class StackServices extends Service {
private Handler mPeriodicEventHandler;
private static final String TAG = "Debug";
private static final long WAITING_TIME = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; //24 hours
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "Service Created");
    mPeriodicEventHandler = new Handler();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mPeriodicEventHandler.removeCallbacks(doPeriodicConnect);
    Log.d(TAG, "Service Destroyed");
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Service started a command");
    mPeriodicEventHandler.post(doPeriodicConnect); //in order to load url when service starts
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
private Runnable doPeriodicConnect = new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
        String url = "http://www.stackOverflow.com";
        loadURL(url);

        mPeriodicEventHandler.postDelayed(doPeriodicConnect, WAITING_TIME);
    }
};
private void loadURL(String url) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("Service loaded on: %s", calendar.getTime() ));
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    intent.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

I am starting the `Service` by clicking on a button, and my `Activity` implements `OnClickListener`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int viewId = view.getId();

    switch (viewId){
        case R.id.btnStartStopService:
            if (isServiceRunning){
                this.stopService(new Intent(this, StackServices.class));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.service_shutdown, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnStartStopService.setText(getString(R.string.btn_start_service));
                Log.d("Debug","service is running and you clicked shutdown"); //TODO delete me
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.service_started, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                this.startService(new Intent(this, StackServices.class));
                Log.d("Debug", "service is not running and you clicked start"); //TODO delete me
                finish();
            }
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.dont_know_what_to_do, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

So far so good, but something is wrong, When I start the service with the button and during the 24 hours period I open and close the application several times, my service is recreating and loads the site again. I am wondering why..?

That is not appropriate behavior for me. I wrote some `Log.d()` messages to see what happens.

- Debug: Activity created
- Debug: service running check
- Debug: service is not running and you clicked start
- Debug: Service Created
- Debug: Service started a command
- Debug: Service loaded on: Thu Feb 25 10:08:11 GMT+02:00 2016
- Debug: Activity destroyed
- Debug: Activity created
- Debug: service running check
- Debug: Activity destroyed
- Debug: Activity created
- Debug: service running check
- Debug: Activity destroyed
- Debug: Activity created
- Debug: service running check
- Debug: Service Created
- Debug: Service started a command
- Debug: Service loaded on: Thu Feb 25 10:08:53 GMT+02:00 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Service returns `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`.

This means although it may be destroyed by the system at some time it will then be recreated. One important detail:

> if there are not any pending start commands to be delivered to the service, it will be called with a null intent object, so you must take care to check for this.

(From the [documentation for START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY))

To avoid frequent reloading of the webpage, you can change your `onStartCommand()` method like this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null)
    {        
        // only do this when started by activity
        mPeriodicEventHandler.post(doPeriodicConnect); 
    }
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

But maybe you should also reconsider if you really need a `Service` running 24/7. Take a look at `AlarmManager`, see this [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Comment: but in Log I didn't see "service Destroyed", I have Log.d(TAG, "Service Destroyed"); onDestroy Method. I have read for `AlarmManager` but API is 19 I want to run service in lower API's.

Comment: @MeLine - onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called. But you see the Service was created. As it is a kind of Singleton, this means it was previously destroyed

Comment: @MELine - AlarmManager was around since API level 1, only in level 19 the behaviour was changed, see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: @[0x0nosugar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5015207/0x0nosugar) My mistake about the API`s thanks.